# Trackball alternatives

Tags: trackball

Are there any trackball manufacturers other than Logitech or Kensington who make a trackball that has most, if not all, of the following design specifications:

1. Large ball to be manipulated by the fingers rather than the thumb.
2. Buttons that serve the purpose of left-click and right-click that operate with the thumb
3. Scroll wheel
4. Scroll wheel accessible with the thumb

The Logitech Trackman meets the first three criteria, but not the fourth. The newer Logitech marble trackballs all place the ball under the thumb. Kensington products (at least those that I have seen), lack three and four.

At this point, I am seriously looking at buying an old MS Trackball Explorer off eBay for in excess of $250.

Are there any alternatives not on my list that might be effective and below that price point?

Comment: Do you mean kensington instead of kingston? kingston makes memory and related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

**[Kensington 64325 Black 4 Buttons USB Wired TrackBall](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16826125017)**

[image]

- DiamondEye Optical tracking for superior accuracy
- Award-winning Scroll Ring for precise fingertip scrolling
- Exceptional comfort for ultimate productivity
- Large ball for maximum precision and control
- Detachable wrist rest cradles hand in comfort

Comment: Molly, The Kensington model has a rep of not working full out with anything past WinXP. The play is for the machine it ends up on running W7 64-bit with a series of VirtualBox sessions running WinXP. It's not beyond the realm to have a VB VM trackball and one for the rest of the time, but ... I'd prefer having heard wrong. Second question, is the scroll ring clickable (to double as middle-click?) Thanks for helping out. GM

Comment: *> Molly, The Kensington model has a rep of not working full out with anything past WinXP.* Hence why you specifically said *other than Logitech or Kensington*.

Answer (score 1):

the best trackball of all time that you all would have loved was the Kensington Orbit. You could rest your hand on it to REST, and manipulate the ball with your fingers, as the ball was in Front, and the fingers and thumb dropped down to click things. Did not have a scroll wheel, but who cares. Then kensington came out with the abomination you see above. I bouthg it and it was instant carpel tunnel until I tried to tilt it in the other direction by putting tons of padding under it, and giving myself a palm rest. Pathetic. I still have my orbit but could not clean it well enough after 8 years.

Comment: Tristan, I've always been in favour of a large ball roller myself. The original Logitech trackball was great for that. But in the current Windows world, scroll wheels are vital. As such, the Kensington models just wouldn't work for my needs. GM

Answer (score 0):

I thought your last question was fine.

I'm looking for the same thing. Have you found anything you like yet? I'd like to know what you settled on.

From what I've read the Kensington above is a step down from its previous versions.
It runs on pins instead of rollers, it's now slanted such that the wrist is bent up,
and the 'Award-winning Scroll Ring' is poorly implemented. No click on the ring, BTW.

I'm looking at the [L-Trac](http://clearlysuperiortech.com/highperformance.html) myself. There isn't much info on the web about it, but what I've found is positive (geekhack.com).

Good luck.

Comment: Thinman, a family member tired of me grousing about my dead MS Trackball Explorer and bought one off EBay for me. Means I have to be nice to my mother for a year or so, but cheap at twice the price (to me!).

After reading your comment, I did look at the link. Looks awkward to me being all rectangular angles. Plus the scroll wheel seems badly placed UNLESS you actuall use your palm to move the trackball. Me, I use the fingers. Still, IF it gets to market I'll certainly try to put my hand on one.

By the way, the Kensington was a dud. And talking to their local sales reps was a waste of time!

Comment: Gary - glad you found a good solution.
Currently I'm using my trusty marble mouse along with USB Overdrive. This utility provides scrolling with the ball on the mac. It resolves the only real issue I had with the marble, other than just the itch to try something different :)